# XML file header in Biztalk

Tags: .net, xml, biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-mapper

I want to add a xml header as below

```
<?xml version='1.1' encoding='utf-8'?>

<!DOCTYPE CrtlFile PUBLIC "-//Biz//CtrlFile_1_1//EN""CrtlFile_1_1.dtd">
```

I already tried the Add processing instructions text and Add XML Declaration options on pipeline, But it didn't solve my requirements.

Please advise on how can I achieve this through BizTalk.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set your own custom xml declaration at design time in your pipeline component.

In the "Add processing instructions text" field you should put

```
<?xml version='1.1' encoding='utf-8'?> <!DOCTYPE CrtlFile PUBLIC "-//Biz//CtrlFile_1_1//EN""CrtlFile_1_1.dtd">
```

Don't forget to set the Add XML Declaration to false